# python hierarchical clustering - flipping nodes while maintaining valid linkages

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-analysis, hierarchical

I am trying to cluster an nxm dataset using hierarchical clustering and display the dendrogram and heatmap.

Based on examples online, the following code generates my linkage map (Y1) given the dataset in dat:

```
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch
import scipy.spatial.distance as ssd

d1 = ssd.pdist(dat)
D1 = ssd.squareform(d1)  # full matrix
Y1 = sch.linkage(D1, method=method, metric=metric)
```

I then use Y1 to reorder my heat map, which works.

I then generate a dendrogram using

```
sch.dendrogram(Y1, orientation='top', color_threshold=0.0)
```

Now, however, I would now like to "flip" a given node (such that the linkage is preserved, but the cluster ordering is reversed). In the example below, I would be flipping across node x.

```
                     |
                |----x---|
                |        |
                |     |-----|
            |-----|   |     |
            a     b   c     d
```

should become

```
                     |
                |----x---|
                |        |
            |-----|      |
            |     |   |-----|
            c     d   a     b
```

The dendgrogram method has an option to sort by distance, but this doesn't allow for arbitrary node flipping.

I can't seem to find any examples of people doing this - any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!